# "What's New" is missing in Software Centre

Tags: software-center

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04.01 and noticed that the `What's New` section in the Software Centre is missing.

Has this happened to anyone else? How will I discover new apps now?

Comment: 12.10 has 'Whats new', you can upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and then re-install Ubuntu `Software Center`:

Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  simultaneously to open the terminal.

**To uninstall Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get remove software-center`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`

**To re-install Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get install software-center`
2. `sudo apt-get update`

that should bring it back...